# Authenticating with API token to freshDesk using iron-ajax

Tags: ajax, authentication, polymer

The [documentation here](http://developer.freshdesk.com/api/#authentication) shows them using `curl` to authenticate in all the examples.  There are also [some examples here](https://github.com/freshdesk/fresh-samples/) for various languages.  However, I am trying to use the API with [polymer](/questions/tagged/polymer)'s `iron-ajax` element and I'm having trouble authenticating.

I tried basing it off their nodejs sample and including it in the params, but it's still not working.

```
<template is="dom-bind" id="app">
    <iron-ajax auto
               url="https://<mydomain>.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets"
               params='{ "user": "<myapitoken>", "pass": "X", "sendImmediately": "true" }'
               handle-as="json"
               last-response="{{ajaxResponse}}"></iron-ajax>

    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[ajaxResponse.items]]">
        <mhc-ticket ticket-id="[[item.id]]"></mhc-ticket>
    </template>

</template>
```

I just get a `401 (Unauthorized)`.  How am I supposed to authenticate?

Answer (score 1):

I had to move the parameters to the header, set `with-credentials` to true and force the `method` to "GET".  It works now:

```
<template is="dom-bind" id="app">
    <iron-ajax auto
               url="https://<mydomain>.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets"
               headers='{ "user": "<myapikey>", "pass": "X", "sendImmediately": "true" }'
               handle-as="json"
               method="GET"
               last-response="{{ajaxResponse}}"
               with-credentials></iron-ajax>

    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[ajaxResponse.items]]">
        <mhc-ticket ticket-id="[[item.id]]"></mhc-ticket>
    </template>

</template>
```